# Avoid multiple definitions of a class for different types containing the same method

Tags: java

I have 2 classes as such:

```
public class A {
    private String label;

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}

public class B {
    private String label;

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}
```

Then I have another class where I want to access these classes' label values:

```
public class C {
    private String label;

    public C(A object) {
        label = object.getLabel();
    }
}
```

For example, the above definition only works for A. I want to be able to pass either A or B to C's constructor. The closest thing I can think of is to make C a generic class but then I lose access to getLabel(). How can I go on about this? I feel like this is a basic design pattern but since I'm new to Java, I don't know where to start. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Inheritance is what you might be looking for?

Comment: If `A` and `B` have no other commonality, then interfaces are the way to go, as suggested by @Anderson Viera.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create an [interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) and make both `A` and `B` implement it:

```
interface HasLabel {
    String getLabel();
}
```

Then

```
public class A implements HasLabel { ... }

public class B implements HasLabel { ... }
```

And in `C`:

```
public class C {
    private String label;

    public C(HasLabel object) {
        label = object.getLabel();
    }
}
```

When you do `C(HasLabel object)` you guarantee that `getLabel()` can be called on the argument, so it allows you to do `object.getLabel()`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can create a common superclass, which defines a abstract method `public String getLabel()` and let `A` and `B` inherit from this superclass.

Comment: So this is what interfaces are for! Thank you for the quick implementation. I prefer this over extending a common base class since I'm already extending another class in my real code.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple in Java using inheritance and polymorphism:

This is an abstract base class that implements the common behaviour:

```
public abstract class Base {
    private String label;

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}
```

`A` and `B` are subclasses of `Base` and inherit their behaviour:

```
public class A extends Base {
    // specific fields / methods of class A
}

public class B extends Base {
    // specific fields / methods of class B
}
```

You can now use instances of `A` and `B` in `C` using the base type `Base`:

```
public class C {
    private String label;

    public C(Base object) {
        label = object.getLabel();
    }
}
```

E.g.:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();

C c1 = new C(a);
C c2 = new C(b);
```